# Getting ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk when lazy laoding Translation in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, lazy-loading

I am trying to implement Lazy load translations for my Vuejs application and following this guide: https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/lazy-loading.html
Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks In Advance!

File structure is something like this:

```
src/translations
   -- AllMessages.ts
   -- bg-BG.json
   -- da-DK.json
   -- en.json 
   ....... more json files here
```

my i18n.ts file:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueI18n from "vue-i18n";
// import { allMessages } from "@/translations/allMessages";

Vue.use(VueI18n);
const selectedLanguage: any = 'en' || something.language.split("-")[0];

const loadedLanguages = ["en"];

const getLanguageMessage = async () =>
  await import(/* webpackChunkName: "selectedLanguage-[request]" */ `@/translations/${selectedLanguage}.json`);

const messages: any = { [selectedLanguage]: getLanguageMessage() }; 
console.log("messages", messages); // this promise is rejected, I see in the console

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: selectedLanguage, // "en",
  fallbackLocale: "en",
  messages: messages, // set locale messages
});

console.log("i18n-message", i18n.messages);


export default i18n;
```

In my console I am getting error:

[image]